# Progress bars in bootstrap are jumpy and inaccurate? (fiddle demonstration included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I just found out about bootstrap today and started incorporating their UI elements in to my web app. Unfortunately, I'm having a bit of trouble with their progress bars. I don't know if it's just me but the they see to be jumpy, inaccurate, and stutter quite a bit. Here's a fiddle for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/v255fwkz/2/

If you click `Run` and then `Start`, at least on all my browsers I tested, the first one finishes a couple seconds faster than the second one even though they both should take 10 seconds. Also, the top one kind of zooms in the beginning and then slows down at the end. It's not the same speed throughout. Also the third one doesn't even work. It just instantly goes down after the 10 seconds.

Ideally I'd like to use the top version because it's smoother but in my app I need this to be somewhat accurate because it's functioning as a timer for a user so I'm afraid I'll have to use the bottom one. Hopefully I'm just messing up the code somewhere or I'm missing something. Maybe I should switch from bootstrap to something else?

Comment: This is not a problem with Bootstrap, but rather how the functionality of `transition-duration` (*which tends to be fast at the start and slows down at the end of the transition*) works. For example it works exactly in the same way with normal `<div>` elements ([**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/v255fwkz/3/)).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Why is it bad? is there any way to fix it or get `animate` working?

Comment: It's not bad, that is simply the default behavior which can be changed. The answer by **@kamus**  does this by doing `transition: width 1s linear;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is not about bootstrap problem, it's caused because yo have a duration lower than your interval :     `transition: width .6s ease;`

Another important thing is the easing, if you have a not linear easing the timing function will affect the result. 
And finally you need to call first you     `$("#second").css("width", value + "%");` before to the first interval.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v255fwkz/4/

Comment: How did you find out about this css property? It works perfectly now I'm just wondering where in the docs these things are.

Comment: is not documented in the bootstrap website, i just check the class of the progress bar and see the transition property (originally .6s , and overrided to 1s by me) you can check more about the timing functions here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/

Comment: @JohnSmith It's just normal CSS, generally you would find the docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). To be specific the `liner` part is a [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function).